# Как сложить строку(вывод формулы) с временем которую ввел пользователь

Tags: python

```
x = str(input("Ведите время включения, например:10.00\n"))
x1 = str(40) # допустим формула вывела это значение

x3 = x + x1

print(x3) # И нужно что бы получилось например 10.40 а не 10.0040
```

Comment: Ну так складывай числа, а не строки

Comment: Ну так мне нужно что бы получалось  время, я вас немного не понял, если вам не сложно можете пример показать?

Comment: Значит, складывай время. Открой мануал по любому из модулей, которые для работы с временем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать timedelta из datetime чтобы хранить время

```
from datetime import timedelta

x = input() # 10.40
x2 = int(input()) # 40

h, m = map(int, x.split('.')) # 10, 40

x3 = timedelta(hours = h, minutes = m) + timedelta(minutes = x2)

print(x3) # 10:40:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Время лучше хранить в виде списка или кортежа, где в разных элементах минуты и секунды. И переносить лишние минуты в часы при каждом изменении (7 строка).

```py
time = input('Введите время включения: ')
time = [int(_) for _ in time.split('.')]

duration = 40  # Сюда ваше значение в минутах

time[1] += duration
time = [time[0] + time[1] // 60, time[1] % 60]

print(f'Длительность составляет {duration}')
print(f'Время окончания: {time}')
```

Comment: Попробывал как вы сказали но выдает ошибку  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test\Time.py", line 8, in <module>
    time[1] += duration
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: А как вы время вводили? Время, как у вас в вопросе должно вводиться по формату minutes.seconds. Если вы введете только секунды, работать не будет. Можно ввести 0 в значении минут.

Comment: Читайте ошибку. Ну ясно же, что по какой-то причине нет минут (секунды являются нулевым индексом, а не первым)